# show one row and sum values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query to select invoices and their items from database. I have posted example down below with two invoices having 3 invoice items (I'm using linked servers from MSSQL to Oracle DB).

Example with cID 1616251758086 got 3 positions with same "Stawka VAT" so I would like to show only one row with "Stawka VAT" = 0.23000 but values in "Netto", "VAT", "Brutto" should be summed (commented code with SUM works fine but still shows 3 rows, each one with whole sum).

Example with cID 1616251238669 got 3 positions with different "Stawka VAT" values so it should show output like already does.

I tried bunch of things but with no proper result.

CURRENT CODE:

```
SELECT
    invo.cID, -- ID dokumentu
    cProcessID, -- Dane faktury ERP
    cERPNumber, -- Dane z pola cProcessID
    cERPStatus, -- Wartość zmienia się na 200 po pobraniu danych
    invo.cType as 'Typ dok',
    cINumberExternal as 'Nr dok',
    (CASE WHEN invo.cType = 'creditmemo' THEN cReferencingInvoiceNr ELSE '' END) as 'Korekta',
    cIDateExternal as 'Data wyst',
    cDeliveryDate as 'Data dok',
    cDateOfReceipt AS 'Data wpływu',
    ISNULL(invo_items.cText, '') as 'Treść',
    invo_items.cCurrency as 'Waluta',
    ISNULL(cCurrencyRate, '') as 'Kurs',
    invo_items.cIItemNumber as 'Pozycja faktury',
    invo_items.cTaxRate as 'Stawka VAT',
    invo_items.cNetTotalAmount as 'Netto',
    invo_items.cTaxAmount as 'VAT',
    invo_items.cNetTotalAmount+invo_items.cTaxAmount as 'Brutto',
    --SUM(invo_items.cNetTotalAmount) OVER(Partition by invo_items.ciid, invo_items.cTaxRate) as 'Netto',
    --SUM(invo_items.cTaxAmount) OVER(Partition by invo_items.ciid, invo_items.cTaxRate) as 'VAT',
    --SUM(invo_items.cNetTotalAmount+invo_items.cTaxAmount) OVER(Partition by invo_items.ciid,invo_items.cTaxRate) as 'Brutto',
    cBaselineDate as 'Termin płatności',
    invo.cVendorID as 'VendorID',
    cVendorVatnumber as 'VendorNIP',
    CONCAT(kh.cname, '', kh.cname2) as 'VendorName',
    kh.cStreet as 'Ulica',
    kh.cCity as 'Miasto',
    kh.cCountry as 'Kraj'
FROM ORACLE_OTTO..xxxxxx.INVOICES as invo
    JOIN ORACLE_OTTO..xxxxxx.VENDORMASTERDATA as kh on kh.cvendorid = invo.cvendorid
    JOIN ORACLE_OTTO..xxxxxx.INVOICEITEMS as invo_items on invo.cid = invo_items.ciid
WHERE invo.cID in ('1616251758086', '1616251238669')
```

CURRENT OUTPUT:

| cID | Pozycja faktury | Stawka VAT | Netto | VAT | Brutto |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1616251758086 | 1 | 0.23000 | 4.0000 | 0.9200 | 4.9200 |
| 1616251758086 | 2 | 0.23000 | 1500.0000 | 345.0000 | 1845.0000 |
| 1616251758086 | 3 | 0.23000 | 20981.0000 | 4825.6300 | 25806.6300 |
| 1616251238669 | 1 | 0.23000 | 465.2100 | 107.0000 | 572.2100 |
| 1616251238669 | 2 | 0.08000 | 112.2800 | 8.9800 | 121.2600 |
| 1616251238669 | 3 | 0.05000 | 152.6400 | 7.6300 | 160.2700 |

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

| cID | Pozycja faktury | Stawka VAT | Netto | VAT | Brutto |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1616251758086 | 1,2,3 | 0.23000 | 22485.0000 | 5171.5500 | 27656.5500 |
| 1616251238669 | 1 | 0.23000 | 465.2100 | 107.0000 | 572.2100 |
| 1616251238669 | 2 | 0.08000 | 112.2800 | 8.9800 | 121.2600 |
| 1616251238669 | 3 | 0.05000 | 152.6400 | 7.6300 | 160.2700 |

Comment: Strange, you SELECT 20 columns or so, but only 6 are returned.

Comment: @jarlh I just deleted those that are not important for this case.

Comment: Delete them from the query too. Things should match! [mcve]

Comment: Which version of SQL Server?

Comment: SQL 2019 Standard

Comment: Can `invo_items.cTaxRate` vary between the rows for a given cID value? Seems you need a typical "one per group" solution but it is not clear. I don't understand why you need to "string aggregate" `invo_items.cIItemNumber` if we make assumptions about how it is populated and used. Seems like MAX() for that column gives you the same information without the complication.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using a common table expression would help?

```
with cte as (
select .... -- your query from the question
)
select 
cte.cID, 
cte.cIItemnumber as 'Pozycja faktury',
cte.cTaxRate as 'Stawka VAT', 
SUM(cte.cNetTotalAmount) as 'Netto',
SUM(cte.cTaxAmount) as 'VAT',
SUM(cte.cNetTotalAmount+cte.cTaxAmount) as 'Brutto'
from cte
group by cte.cID, cte.CIItemnumber,cte.cTaxRate
```

Did not try this out of course, but you will get my drift... :)

Answer (score 0):

This one should do your job:

```
SELECT
    invo.cID,
    STUFF((
        SELECT ', ' + CAST(i_qry.cIItemNumber AS varchar)
        FROM ORACLE_OTTO..xxxxxx.INVOICEITEMS i_qry
        WHERE invo.cid = i_qry.ciid
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ), 1, 2, '') AS [Pozycja faktury],
    invo_items.cTaxRate AS [Stawka VAT],
    SUM(invo_items.cNetTotalAmount) AS [Netto],
    SUM(invo_items.cTaxAmount) AS [VAT],
    SUM(invo_items.cNetTotalAmount + invo_items.cTaxAmount) AS [Brutto]
FROM
    ORACLE_OTTO..xxxxxx.INVOICES as invo
    JOIN ORACLE_OTTO..xxxxxx.VENDORMASTERDATA as kh on kh.cvendorid = invo.cvendorid
    JOIN ORACLE_OTTO..xxxxxx.INVOICEITEMS as invo_items on invo.cid = invo_items.ciid
GROUP BY
    invo.cID, invo_items.cTaxRate
```

In this case I assume that ORACLE_OTTO..xxxxxx.INVOICESITEMS.cIItemNumber is a number. In case it is a char/varchar, just remove the `CAST` around it.

Comment: `), 1, 1, '').value('text()','nvarchar(max)') AS [Pozycja faktury],`

Comment: Why use `value()`? What does it add to the query?

Comment: You need to avoid XML escaping. See https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/63445/avoiding-entitized-characters-when-using-for-xml-path-for-string-concatenation and https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/207371/please-explain-what-does-for-xml-path-type-value-nvarcharmax Sorry the exact incantation is `FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '')` Note also that the second `1` paramter for `STUFF` represents the length of the separator `,`, so in your case you want `, 1, 2, '')`

Comment: I said it wrong: what does it add to the query since it is a numeric ID (I don't need XML escaping)? True your second observation: I fix it immediately, thanks

Comment: You shouldn't rely on implicit conversions, in any case, just wait 5 minutes til someone uses this code for text. We are beholden to the rest of the world to give them reliable code

Comment: I'm using `CAST(i_qry.cIItemNumber AS varchar)`,  so it is quite an explicit convention.
You're probably right, but I've answered a specific question: the rest of the world will do equally specific ones.

Comment: **1.** `CAST(... as varchar)` with no size is *also* implicit as you are relying on the default length, [the docs say](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/char-and-varchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) "When n isn't specified in a data definition or variable declaration statement, the default length is 1. If n isn't specified when using the CAST and CONVERT functions, the default length is 30." **2.** That is *inside* the XML, I was talking about once the XML is generated, when you should convert it back to text properly rather than rely on it not having escaped chars

Comment: You have won: in practice you are doing philosophy and I am not good in this field :D